# Removing commands used before loading package

Tags: packages, contexts

**Original Question**:  I used the convert command before loading the Units package.

```
Convert[20000. Feet, Mile]
```

Since `Convert` isn't defined, it returns unevaluated. Now if I load the units package, the function evaluates, but the symbols `Convert`, `Feet`, and `Mile` are highlighted in red by the front-end:

```
Needs["Units`"]
(* Convert::shdw: Symbol Convert appears in multiple contexts {Units`,Global`}; definitions in context Units` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >> *)

Convert[20000. Feet, Mile]
(* 3.78788 Mile *)
```

I know I could restart the kernel and load the package, but how else can I proceed at this point to get rid of the shadowed definitions and make everything work properly?

I tried `Remove[Convert,Mile,Feet]`, but then `Convert` no longer works (expected), then I tried reloading the package, but the command still doesn't work.

**Fix for my problem**:  According to the helpful comments and the answer by @Szabolcs, it seems my mistake was not paying attention to the context of the symbols that were shadowed. The following code shows one way to solve the issue I encountered:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

```
Remove[Global`Convert]
```

instead of

```
Remove[Convert]
```

`Convert` is coloured red as a warning because both `` Units`Convert `` and `` Global`Convert `` exist, so when you simply type `Convert` one of the two has to be chosen, which *might* not be the one you wanted.

Comment: @Szaboics: That did not seem to work, see my posting at the end of my question.

Comment: @David Actually it does work.  I try not to post answers without testing them.  What likely happened in your case was that first you `Remove`d ``Units`Convert`` (`Remove[Convert]` does that), and *then* you removed ``Global`Convert`` as well.  Then you tried re-loading the package using `Needs`, which did not have any effect as the package was already loaded.  `Needs` differs from `Get` precisely in that it doesn't read packages that are already loaded.

Comment: Does is make sense to include the differences between `Get` and `Needs` in your answer as well?  It seems as if they go nicely together with your comments on `Remove`, making a more canonical answer.

Comment: @Szaboics: Your last comment was correct and you can view the results above in my original question under the heading **Second Attempt at Fixing the Problem**. Thanks for your effort. I've learned a lot.

Comment: @David If you accidentally remove ``Units`Convert``, you can re-load the package using ``<<Units` ``.  This only differs from ``Needs["Units`"]`` in that it doesn't have a re-load protection.